# Направление сырых данных в USB

Tags: android, аудио, usb

Есть задача снимать звук с микрофона Android телефона и отправлять через USB на другой Android. Как работать на стороне Host понятно. Вот непонятно как организовать работу на стороне телефона который производит данные. Т.е. когда данные уже есть, как отправлять их в USB так чтобы на другой стороне из уже считывать?